# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'GCPPixel'

Tags: python, gdal, qgis, pyqgis

I'm new in coding and trying to translate SEVIRI native images to tif format using gdal library and qgis python console.
The problem is when I want to add GCPs I get an error and I don't know how to solve this problem I know I add GCP in the wrong way but I don't know what is the proper method!
I searched alot but didn't find anything about adding GCPs in qgis python console while using gdaltranslate. Any suggestions will help.
Here is my code in qgis python console :

```
import gdal
src='E:/data/MSG1-SEVI-MSG15-0100-NA-20190331061240.466000000Z-20190331061258-1408742.nat'

dst='E:/data/trans.tif'

ds=gdal.Open(src)

gdal.Translate(dst,ds,format='GTiff',outputType=gdal.GDT_UInt16,GCPs=(3227050.38610344,1303713.87878049,50.2665350843959,29.244462081302))

error is

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.14\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.14\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py", line 422, in Translate
    (opts, callback, callback_data) = TranslateOptions(**kwargs)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.14\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py", line 376, in TranslateOptions
    new_options += ['-gcp', _strHighPrec(gcp.GCPPixel), _strHighPrec(gcp.GCPLine), _strHighPrec(gcp.GCPX), str(gcp.GCPY), _strHighPrec(gcp.GCPZ)]
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'GCPPixel'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is what you're passing as the `GCPs` parameter to the `gDal.Translate` function. You're passing a list (tuple) of floating point values, when what that parameter expects is a list of `gdal.GCP()` objects.

Because the library thinks it has `gdal.GCP()` objects, it is trying to call the `GCPPixel` method on one of them, which would work if that's what it was.  But it's a float, and of course, floating point numbers don't have a `GCPPixel` method, hence the error you're getting.

Comment: First of all, I have to say thank you for answering my question. You are absolutely right and I dont know how to create such GCP objects in qgis python console.Do know where can I find more about this?

Comment: thank you very much for your help I used gdal.GCP() and it worked!. but there is one more big problem and it is when I add more than 5 gcp my data set will be lost ! I will add this problem as a new question

Comment: You've thanked me twice, but given me no official credit, LOL!  I don't really care.  I'm really just here to help.